# Infopath Formule Creation without code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have created the form like below

Star Date : DatePicker

ADd days: Textbox

DueDate: datePicker.

So when the user selects a start date and Add days then the Due date should be displayed based on the calculation of Startdate+add days.

For ex: Is start date is 6/23/2013 and Add days is 7 then due date should be 6/30/2013.

Can you give formule in infopath form or a list.

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a rule on the "Add Days" text box that gets executed when the field is changed.

Let the rule set the value of the DueDate field. Use the function

```
addDays(Date,Days)
```

Set the first parameter to the "Start Date" field and the second parameter to the "Add Days" field

[image]

Comment: A good answer with a nice, explanatory image deserves an upvote!

Comment: It works perfectly. thanks .Similarly can i set the time as well??

Comment: @sandy_9866141457, if this solves your question, please mark it as the answer, so that other people can see that there is a solution. As to the time: no, it's not as easy. There is a function called addSeconds(), so you would have to convert any time value into seconds first. That can be a bit tricky for a beginner. You may want to start a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks i think i need to have 15 score to vote up this answer. @ robert can you vote for this answer on behalf of me